# Force computer name to resolve to local IP on Windows Server 2008 Network?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, netbios, domain-name-system

Here's the scenario: 3 Windows Server 2008 machines, each connected to 2 networks: a public network open to the internet and also a private LAN

```
netbios/
comp name  local IP
-------- ----------------
server1  192.168.112.10
server2  192.168.112.11
server3  192.168.112.12
```

'ping server1' from server2 or 3 will resolve to server1's local IP 192.168.112.10.

likewise

'ping server2' from server1 or 3 will resolve to server2's local IP 192.168.112.11.

The problem I have is that from server1 and 2 when I 'ping server3' I get the public IP address.  I to resolve server3 to the local IP 192.168.112.12 in order to connect services via the safe Local Network, rather than poking holes in the public firewall!

*Please bear with me since I'm more of a DBA than a Server Admin.*

cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One work around you may do is open the file  c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in Server 1 and Server 2 and add the entry

192.168.112.12 server3

This will force both the servers to use the local IP.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I would give you a vote if I had the reputation, however this is the first question from a longtime lurker!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. My best guess at the moment is it's a DNS issue.

Is DNS running on any of the servers?

If you were to drop to a command-prompt on each server and type "nslookup," what DNS server are the servers set to poll first?

Is Server 3 connected to a switch within the LAN? Or is it possibly connection to a DMZ port on a firewall?

What IP do you get when you ping "server3" *on* server3?

Comment: Thanks.
ping server3 on server3 returned an IP V6 IP address.  The LAN is configured for IPV4 only, so there's one problem.
There are switches and a possibly badly configured attempt at a local DNS which could be the cause.
However, proy's simple answer did the trick.